# GWT ERROR RPCManager performTransactionReply: No such transaction

Tags: json, gwt, smartgwt

I'm using SmartGWT -4.0 and tried to run the example of using DataSource with Json , RestDataSourceWithJson.zip .
but the development mode console returns me the following error :

```
[ ERROR ] [ restdatasourcewithjson ] 10:55:28.214 : XRP4 : WARN : RPCManager : performTransactionReply : No such transaction 0
com.smartgwt.client.core.JsObject $ SGWT_WARN : 10:55:28.214 : XRP4 : WARN : RPCManager : performTransactionReply : No such transaction 0
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInsta nce0 ( Native Method )
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInsta nce ( NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java : 57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newI nstance ( DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java : 45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance ( Constructor.java : 525 )
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke ( MethodAdaptor.java : 105)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke ( MethodDispatch.java : 71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invok e ( OophmSessionHandler.java : 172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reac tToMessages ( BrowserChannelServer.java : 293)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.proc essConnection ( BrowserChannelServer.java : 547)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run ( BrowserChannelServer.java : 364 )
at java.lang.Thread.run ( Thread.java : 722 )
```

this happens to any other project that uses json .
has anyone had this error ?

thanks for the help .

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting this too when running a REST webapp using Smartgwt Datasources and XML messaging with Jersey, under Chrome. Other browsers don't throw this error.

You will get errors in that situation because running a Smartgwt app under Chrome is not supported (albeit sometimes useful to check what your CSS looks like), so I would just say use another browser for dev mode.

Source:
Smartgwt user guide, and this thread: http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=30289